# How can you search for, install and include/link C libraries on a mac?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, package

I already have brew and xcode installed.

I'm trying to install the lz4 C library.

On Ubuntu I'd use:

`apt search lz4`

`sudo apt install liblz4-dev`

On Windows I'd use `vcpkg`.

How do you do it on a MacOs (v 11.3.1)?

I've tried:

`brew install lz4`

But my IDE isn't detecting the installed library or header file, so I'm assuming that's just the command line version.

Edit: CLion does not automatically detect libraries from your `usr` sub-directories, adding include targets using Cmake found the headers and libraries that `brew` did indeed install.

Comment: I haven't set up anything with it, but I think its possible with [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org).

Answer (score 2):

You might have to add `-I /opt/homebrew/include -L /opt/homebrew/lib -llz4` to your compiler flags in the project settings. `/opt/homebrew` is for m1 macs, replace that with `/usr/local` if you're on intel.

Comment: oh you're right, there's the header file in usr/local/include. Attempting to add targets to CLion settings.

Comment: Adding `target_include_directories(Target_Name PRIVATE /usr/local/include)` to the `CMakeLists.txt` file solved the problem. Brew really does download the dev library.

Comment: Obviously to get it to link, I'll need a corresponding `target_link_directories` call.